# Boolean function changes returned datatype when output streams are added

Tags: powershell

I'm having some trouble understanding the inner workings on powershell. Take this example. I have a boolean function (Test-MyCode), that works fine, as long as the Write-Output cmdlet is left out. Once the Write-Output cmdlet is added, the return type changes to a Object[] array.

.GetType() can be used to view the datatype.

Why is this?

```
function Test-MyCode
{
    if( 2 -gt 0)
    {
        Write-Output "This function will return false"
        return $false
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Output "could return true if condition is changed"
        return $true
    }
}

function Invoke-MyCode
{
    Write-Output "this is main"
    Write-Output "do stuff"
    # Test-MyCode is configured to return false... yet its true
    if (Test-MyCode)
    {
        Write-Output "yep, no longer boolean"
    }

}

Invoke-MyCode
```

Comment: Write-Output outputs to the data stream. So your function would be returning that output + the boolean. Use Write-Host instead to just send output to the host.

Comment: Write-Host are just pixels on the screen... i need a proper outputstream because im running this powershell inside our deployment application. Write-Host cannot be captured.

Comment: Then you need to accept that your function will return more than just a boolean.

Comment: @EBGreen why not add this as answer?

Comment: to be honest because it felt like an XY question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `Get-Help Write-Output`:

```
NAME
    Write-Output

SYNOPSIS
    Sends the specified objects to the next command in the pipeline. If the
    command is the last command in the pipeline, the objects are displayed in
    the console.
```

I think your main confusion stems from the fact that **PowerShell functions are not statically bound to return a certain type**.

The `return` keyword doesn't work exactly like in `C#`, but roughly means:

1. Call `Write-Ouput` on the results of the expression after the `return` keyword
2. Exit the current scope

See the [`about_Return`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847760.aspx),[`about_Functions`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847829.aspx) and [`about_Functions_OutputTypeAttribute`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847829.aspx) help files for more information

---

In the simple example above, I would be attracted to creating a new custom object that contains both the string and the result, but the applicability of this "solution" may vary:

```
function Test-MyCode
{
    if( 2 -gt 0)
    {
        New-Object psobject -Property @{
            Message = "This function will return false"
            Result  = $false
        }
    }
    else
    {
        New-Object psobject -Property @{
            Message = "could return true if condition is changed"
            Result  = $true
        }
    }
}

function Invoke-MyCode
{
    Write-Host "this is main"
    Write-Host "do stuff"
    # Test-MyCode is configured to return false... yet its true
    if (($codetest = Test-MyCode).Result)
    {
        Write-Host $codetest.Message
    }
}

Invoke-MyCode
```

Notice how `Write-Output` is implied when I just "dump" an object onto the pipeline with `New-Object`

Comment: Looks like i just did a lot of assumption based scripting :) back to the books. Thanks for the wake-up.